# How to create a entity key form field

Tags: haskell, yesod, yesod-forms

I want to create a new form field to enter an entity key, in this case an ArticleId instead of an Integer field, can I do that?

There is my Article model

```
Article
    title     Text
    content   Text
    userId    Int
    score     Int Maybe
    deriving  Show
    deriving  Eq
```

And there is my AForm Article handler

```
<$> areq intField (bfs ("Article Id" :: Text)) Nothing
<*> areq intField (bfs ("Tag Id" :: Text))     Nothing
```

I want to do this to avoid use toSqlKey in my selectList

Thanks!

Comment: Why do you want to avoid it? It is exactly how I'm converting keys coming from frontend to Persistent ones.

Comment: Actually im using toSqlKey, its only to search a different possibility or only syntactic sugar